# form validations drop ng-model objects?

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs, validation

Say I have the following form:

```
 <form>
    <input type="text" required ng-model='myValue' ng-maxlength='5'></input>
    {{myValue}}
    {{myValue.length}}
 </form>
```

When the length of the text in the input exceeds the maxlength, the model becomes empty. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour while applying this validation, without rolling a custom form level validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first, input element no end mark(`</input`), the correct like this:`<input name="test" type="text"/>`

you can handle form.test.$error.maxlength to deal something, example code:

```
<form name="form">
  <input name="name" type="text" required ng-model='myValue' ng-maxlength='5'/>
  <div>value:{{myValue}}</div>
  <div>length:{{myValue.length}}</div>
  <div>validate:{{form.name.$error.maxlength}}</div>
</form>
```

According your means, the invalid value lead to null model, I think this is no problem.